# External Bluetooth 4.0 dongle on 2009 iMac

Tags: ios, imac, bluetooth

I have a late 2009 iMac and I am developing a BLE app for iOS. At this point of time I don't have an iPhone or an iPad either to test the app on, so I have to user the simulator for the same. My questions are

Can I test Bluetooth functions on a simulator?

Will the external Bluetooth 4.0 dongle work for the app (will it not clash with the in-build Bluetooth 2.1)?